# Pandas - what is exactly "label" and where is it defined?

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas documents, the term **label** is used as if it is granted that we know what it is, such as in [Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).

> The axis **labeling** information in pandas objects serves many purposes:

> pandas provides a suite of methods in order to have purely **label** based indexing. This is a strict inclusion based protocol. Every **label** asked for must be in the index, or a KeyError will be raised. When slicing, both the start bound AND the stop bound are included, if present in the index. Integers are valid **labels**, but they refer to the **label** and not the position.

But what is exactly **label** in Pandas and where is it formally defined? I believe we define the terminology first before using it.

Are they "a column name", "list of column names", "range of columns defined as a slice", "row index", "list of row indices", "range of rows defined as slice"?

Comment: i believe it is defined in the docs: [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing). If it is unclear, a PR could help to improve it. Labels are the values in the index and/or columns. Labels are different from positions, in the sense that labels can be anything that can be held in the index/columns, usually sth hashable, whereas positions are strictly integers

Comment: "Every label asked for must be in the index". I understand that as the definition for label: a label is a sample of index value.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation you linked to we can gather some examples of 'labels':

> - A single label, e.g. 5 or 'a' (Note that 5 is interpreted as a label of the index. This use is not an integer position along the index.).
> - A list or array of labels ['a', 'b', 'c'].
> - A slice object with labels 'a':'f' (Note that contrary to usual Python slices, both the start and the stop are included, when present in the index! See [Slicing with labels](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-slicing-with-labels) and [Endpoints are inclusive](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-endpoints-are-inclusive).)

Therefore, we can conclude that a 'label' is a named value of the index (not being the integer position).